# System::Double::NaN in System::Windows::Forms::DataGridView

Tags: sorting, datagridview, c++-cli, nan, value-type

In a C++ / CLI project, I have a System::Windows::Forms::DataGridView object that displays some values of type double. In some cases, the values contain some System::Double::NaN instances that are displayed as "Non numérique" in the DataGridViewCell (my Windows is in french). I have handled this by displaying "-" if IsNaN(value) returns true. The problem is, when I click on a column's header to sort the values, an exception is thrown because "-" is not of type Double.

Is there a way to store System::Double::NaN as the cell's value, but display something else in the DataGridView cell ?

Comment: Use the CellFormatting event to convert NaN to "-".  Use the CellParsing event to go back from "-" to NaN.